# GAE Java API Channel

Tags: api, google-app-engine, gwt, channel

In http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Channel you
can read that with billing enabled the maximum channel created rate is 60
creations/minute. Does it mean that we can created only 86,400
channels/day. It's very low rate, isn't it? And if i have estimated  that I
could have peaks of for example: 4,000 creations/minute... What i can do?
60 creations/minute are few creations if the channels are 1to1... Is this
correct?

Comment: Did you find out whether this is actually the case and whether any other alternatives are available?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of that section is that you will NOT be able to create 4k connections per minute. Here is how I would think about it: over ANY 1-minute period, no more than 60 channels can be created. For example, you can create 60 channels at time T. Then, for the next 60 seconds you won't be able to create any. Or, you can create 30 at time T. Then, every 2 seconds, create a channel.

I believe another way to think about this is in terms of the [token bucket algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket).

Anyway, I believe you can fill out [this form](http://support.google.com/code/bin/request.py?&contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest) to request a higher limit. There is a link to that form from the docs that you linked to in your question.